# Phrase:I can't remember what (_something_) WAS THAT/IS THAT

Tags: tense, phrases

Let's say you are watching a video clip, then while watching, there is a portion that suddenly reminds you of a book. You **know** that book but you **can't recall** its name. And you say:

> "I can't remember what book **is** that''

Or

> "I can't remember what book **was** that

Which is correct between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't remember  *what book that is.*

I can't remember *what book that was*.

Both **is** and **was** are grammatically correct (the choice would depend on what **that** refers to in context) but the word order in the clause must be as above.

> One of these books has a treasure map in it. What book is that?
>   --I've seen it, but I cannot remember what book that is.

or

> You were telling me when we last met about a book you had once read
>   that had a profound impact on you.  What was its title again?
>   --I cannot remember what book that was.  There have been many such books!

Comment: Excellent! My face just lightened up coz' this is a useful phrase, more likely you could use it often in the future.

Comment: Also, it's common to use "it" rather than "that" in statements like this. "I can't remember what book it is."

Answer (score 3):

What book is that? = is a question form in English. It is interrogative.

**I can't remember what book that is/that was**.

If you are making a statement, you would not use the interrogative form in a sentence. You have to use a phrasal object.